# Coq theorem proving: Simple fraction law in peano arithmetic

Tags: coq, theorem-proving, peano-numbers

I am learning coq and am trying to prove equalities in peano arithmetic.

I got stuck on a simple fraction law.

We know that (n + m) / 2 = n / 2 + m / 2 from primary school.
In peano arithmetic this does only hold if n and m are even (because then division produces correct results).

```
Compute (3 / 2) + (5 / 2). (*3*)
Compute (3 + 5) / 2. (*4*)
```

So we define:

```
Theorem fraction_addition: forall n m: nat , 
    even n -> even m ->  Nat.div2 n + Nat.div2 m = Nat.div2 (n + m).
```

From my understanding this is a correct and provable theorem.
I tried an inductive proof, e.g.

```
intros n m en em.
induction n.
- reflexivity.
- ???
```

Which gets me into the situation that

`en = even (S n)` 
and `IHn : even n -> Nat.div2 n + Nat.div2 m = Nat.div2 (n + m)`, so i don't find a way to apply the induction hypothesis.

After long research of the standard library and documentation, i don't find an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to strengthen your induction hypothesis in cases like this.
One way of doing this is by proving an induction principle like this one:

```
From Coq Require Import Arith Even.
Lemma nat_ind2 (P : nat -> Prop) :
  P 0 ->
  P 1 ->
  (forall n, P n -> P (S n) -> P (S (S n))) ->
  forall n, P n.
Proof.
now intros P0 P1 IH n; enough (H : P n /\ P (S n)); [|induction n]; intuition.
Qed.
```

`nat_ind2` can be used as follows:

```
Theorem fraction_addition n m :
  even n -> even m ->
  Nat.div2 n + Nat.div2 m = Nat.div2 (n + m).
Proof.
  induction n using nat_ind2.
  (* here goes the rest of the proof *)
Qed.
```

Comment: Thanks for the insight. Using this technique I can finish the proof.

Answer (score 2):

You can also prove your theorem without induction if you are ok with using the standard library.

If you use `Even m` in your hypothesis (which says `exists n, m = 2*m`) then you can use simple algebraic rewrites with lemmas from the standard library.

```
Require Import PeanoNat.
Import Nat.

Goal forall n m, Even n -> Even m -> n / 2 + m / 2 = (n+m)/2.
  inversion 1; inversion 1.
  subst.
  rewrite <- mul_add_distr_l.
  rewrite ?(mul_comm 2).
  rewrite ?div_mul; auto.
Qed.
```

The question mark just means "rewrite as many (zero or more) times as possible".

`inversion 1` does inversion on the first inductive hypothesis in the goal, in this case first `Even n` and then `Even m`. It gives us `n = 2 * x` and `m = 2 * x0` in the context, which we then substitute.

Also note `even_spec: forall n : nat, even n = true <-> Even n`, so you can use `even` if you prefer that, just rewrite with `even_spec` first...

Comment: Thanks that is very insightful as well